# MYSQL Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, dynamic, permissions, sql-grant

I am basicially trying to write a store procedure to create a user. The sql is as follows:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`john`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_user`(in userstr char(50), in pass char(50))
BEGIN
    declare str char(52);
    declare mypass char(52);
    declare exec_str char(255);

    set str = concat('\'', userstr, '\'@','\'%\'');
    /*set str = concat('\'', userstr);*/
    /*select str;*/
    set mypass = concat('\'', pass, '\'');

    set @t1 = concat('create user ', str,  ' identified by ', mypass, '; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ', str, ' WITH GRANT OPTION;');
    select @t1;
    prepare stmt1 from @t1;
    /*select stmt1;*/
    execute stmt1;
    deallocate prepare stmt1;
END
```

The code above generates the following string below before executing it. But I receive an error.

Sql generated:

## @t1

create user 'example'@'%' identified by 'splat'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'example'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

It then falls over, returning error 1064:
14:48:32    call create_user('example', 'splat')    Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'example'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1

I have no idea what is going on. FYI, I even tried escaping the * after the grant permissions.

The version I am running is: 5.6.20

Hope you can help, I am sure it's going to be something silly. But I can't seem to see the wood for the trees.

Kind regards
John

Comment: Check: [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) - `SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ";" characters).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you've got two statements, not one. So you've got to prepare and execute them separately:

```
set str = concat('\'', userstr, '\'@','\'%\'');
/*set str = concat('\'', userstr);*/
/*select str;*/
set mypass = concat('\'', pass, '\'');

set @t1 = concat('create user ', str,  ' identified by ', mypass, ';');
select @t1;
prepare stmt1 from @t1;
/*select stmt1;*/
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;

set @t2 = CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ', str, ' WITH GRANT OPTION;');

prepare stmt2 from @t2;
execute stmt2;
deallocate prepare stmt2;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go. Interestingly - I thought something similar. I simply put a go; on the end of each statement. I would have thought that the ; character informed the sql engine that each line is a separate statement and processed them accordingly.